# Display custom URLs for individual tabs of quick tab

Tags: uri, blocks

I need to display seperate URL(Deep linking) for individual tabs in a quick tab. I found a javascript fix in this [link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/09/30/drupal-quick-tabs-deep-linking/) . The URL that is displayed has the quicktab name and tab number. It looks something like /test-quicktab-page?qt-test_quicktab=2. I need a more meaningful url to be displayed. For example /test-quicktab-page/world
or /test-quicktab-page/local . How can this be done?

I tried creating a URL alias but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery in external : This is used for you

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var quicktab = jQuery('ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-excel li  a').each(function() {
      var url  = 'test-quicktab-page?qt-test_quicktab=2';
      var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      var arr = href.split('/');
      alert(arr['2']);  /* rechange the index value as your url path */
      if(url == arr['2']) {
        jQuery(this).removeAttr('href');
        jQuery(this).attr('href','/test-quicktab-page/world');
      }
    });
});
```